# Grails failed dependencies from Travis CI

Tags: maven, grails, dependencies

I have a Grails 2.5.6 project that runs tests on Travis CI, and a couple of days ago I started to get errors related to unresolved dependencies.

On my side the app didn't changed any dependencies, it seems something wrong is on the maven repo.

This is the log I'm getting:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2, org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:jar:0.5.2, org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:jar:1.0-grails-2.4, de.odysseus.staxon:staxon:jar:1.2, mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.43, org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.17.1-GA, org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4, com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:jar:2.5.5, org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1, net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0, com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.1, javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.1, org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final, org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.10.Final, org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA, org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:jar:3.1.5.RELEASE, org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:2.0.5, net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.8, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4: 
   Could not transfer artifact cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Forbidden (403) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:jar:0.5.2, de.odysseus.staxon:staxon:jar:1.2, mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.43, org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.17.1-GA, org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4, com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:jar:2.5.5, org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1, net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0, com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.1, javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.1, org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final, org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.10.Final, org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA, org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:jar:3.1.5.RELEASE, org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:2.0.5, net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.8, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4: 
   Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:jar:0.5.2 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Forbidden (403) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: de.odysseus.staxon:staxon:jar:1.2, mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.43, org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.17.1-GA, com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:jar:2.5.5, org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1, net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0, javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.1, net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.8, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4: 
   Could not transfer artifact de.odysseus.staxon:staxon:jar:1.2 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Forbidden (403) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:jar:7.0.55, org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:7.0.55, org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:jar:7.0.55, org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:7.0.55, org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:3.7.2, org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.55:
   Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:jar:7.0.55 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Forbidden (403)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

I don't have any clues on what is going on or how to fix it. Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a recurring issue with Travis accessing Maven Central. See https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6593 and https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/10055

The suggested workaround is to use `sudo: true` in your `.travis.yml`.