# Travis CI build failed: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50

Tags: gradle, kotlin, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I use Gradle for building my Kotlin project and use Travis CI for continuous integration. After merging last pull request I found that Travis CI build was failed. In logs I see next:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

As I understood Gradle couldn't to get Kotlin plugin, but when I tried to build the project locally all was fine (and actually I didn't change anything related to build process). Also I checked availability of mentioned file - 'kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50.pom', I could to open it in browser. Here is my build.gradle config:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

version '1.' +  System.getProperty("buildNumber")

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

What should be the cause of the issue and how can I fix that?

Comment: Related question (different keywords, but same underlying cause IMHO): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095596/14379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a recurring issue with Travis accessing Maven Central. See https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6593 and https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/10055

The suggested workaround is to use `sudo: true` in your `.travis.yml`.

---

*PS I would close this issue as a duplicate instead of answering again, but I can't do that until there is a vote on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095596/14379).*